# Update 3rd party android app

Tags: android

I'm really new to android developement and really I'm only asking to possibly save my company some money. 
I have a 3rd party app that we install via sideloading, whenever this app gets updated we have to manually update every tablet in our fleet. Which can take a while. I've been looking into MDM solution but all seem too expensive for what I want to do. 
Basically I want to have a way to: 
a. check the app version 
b. see if there's a new update on the server 
c. download the update and install it on the device. Possibly silently

I'm sure it's actually a lot more involved than it sounds but I also don't think it's worth 4000 a month to update one app. We'll be upgrading soon to the samsung galaxy tab e. Any idea on how to possibly perform this task? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy it as a closed beta to the Google play store and invite your users to it.  Then when you push a new beta version to google play everyone will be notified of the update and can download it from there.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7003180

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm looking for something that doesn't involve user interaction. I suppose if there's only a few apps on the device and the device is in kiosk mode it would update the app automatically and not much else.

Answer (score 0):

You could get app's version:

```
PackageInfo pinfo = null;
pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("right.package", 0);
int verCode = pinfo.getVersionCode();
String verName = pinfo.getVersionName();
```

Then go to server and check that newer version exicts, download .apk file.
Installing .apk:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile("new_install.apk");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

It's not a silent installation, user is seeing a dialog.

Comment: Definitely going to try this, thanks so much for the help.